# OpenCart -If products SEO Keyword is filled, OpenCart crashes on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, crash, seo, opencart, keyword

I have an issue in OpenCart.

When the SEO Keyword is filled for a product, it works fine on Firefox and Chrome but on IE (ver 6.) it crashes.

Error:

> The page you are looking for is currently unavailable. The Web site might be experiencing technical difficulties, or you may need to adjust your browser settings.

[eBio link](http://www.ebio.eu/ulei-argan-presat-rece)

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: I found that IE 6 is not supported by OpenCart, so instead of fixing it, I found a workaround [link here](http://www.yoocart.net/156/opencart-tips-display-a-warning-message-to-ie6-users.html) which in fact some code to suggest the visitor to upgrade the browser. I implemented also on my main page here [eBio](http://www.ebio.eu). Of course mine can be seen only on IE6.

Comment: IE6? Cave/Rat People still using it? Go to see a thing called "Internet" - You should find out that there is IE10 to be released soon...

Answer (score 0):

IE6 is no longer supported by Opencart. Daniel, the creater of Opencart says it was too taxing on development time and barely anyone uses it anymore. The people who still do are on old corporate servers and they don't have admin access to upgrade the browser.